# Filtering a dataset and making a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to filter a dataset within `ggplot()`, and display a set of line charts for various countries with a population under 5 million.

I have the dataset locally saved to my computer, but I just put in the github address for convenience.

```
library(ggplot2)
load('https://github.com/inspectordanno/food_production_r/blob/master/countriesbyFood.rdata')

ggplot(countriesbyFood[countriesbyFood$Item=="Wheat and products" & 
                         countriesbyFood$POP_EST < 5000000, ]) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Year, y = Amount, color = Element)) + 
  facet_wrap(~Area)
```

I'm getting:

> Error: Must request at least one colour from a hue palette.

Comment: This appears to be a problem where you have a non-positive column where n must be greater than 0. This is discussed here: [link](https://github.com/r-lib/scales/issues/113)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few changes in the code and it works for me after loading the data.

```
library(tidyverse)

countriesbyFood %>%
   mutate(POP_EST = as.numeric(as.character(POP_EST))) %>%
   filter(Item == "Wheat and products" & POP_EST < 5000000) %>%
   ggplot() + 
   geom_line(aes(x = Year, y=Amount, color=Element)) + 
   facet_wrap(~Area)
```

[image]

Comment: how do you get the plots to be laid out nicely? I'm getting this: https://imgur.com/a/2dSl5tD

Comment: @InspectorDanno If you are using R Studio click on zoom button. It should increase the size of the plot.